# Ninject pass constructor argument typeof class that implements the interface

Tags: c#, ninject, inversion-of-control

I am attempting to use Ninject with my application logging wrapper.

Here is the wrapper:

```
public class NLogLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly Logger _logger;

    public NLogLogger(Type t)
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(t.Name);
    }
}
```

As you can see I am passing the type into the loggers constrctor, so I would use it like the following:

```
public class EntityObject
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public EntityObject()
    {
        Logger = new NLogLogger(typeof(EntityObject));
    }
}
```

Now I cannot seem to find out how to do something similar with using Ninject.
Here is my binding module:

```
public class LoggerModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ILogger>().To<NLogLogger>();
    }
}
```

Now obviously I get an exception thrown because it cannot inject the type into the constructor. Any ideas how I can do this?

> Error activating Type
>
> No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>
> Activation path:
>
> 4) Injection of dependency Type into parameter t of constructor of type NLogLogger
>
> 3) Injection of dependency ILogger into parameter logger of constructor of type NzbGetSettingsService
>
> 2) Injection of dependency ISettingsService{NzbGetSettingsDto} into parameter nzbGetService of constructor of type DashboardController
>
> 1) Request for DashboardController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your classes look like this:

```
public class EntityObject
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; } //it is better by the way to convert this into a private field

    public EntityObject(ILogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

You would need to register your `NLogLogger` like this:

```
Bind<ILogger>().To<NLogLogger>()
    .WithConstructorArgument(
        typeof(Type),
        x => x.Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type);
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I've been pulling my hair out about this one!