# How to use the type being resolved to resolve a dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have several classes that take a dependency of type `ILogger`. The implementation of `ILogger` needs to know the type for which it is the logger, i.e. the `ILogger` for `Foo` will be `new Logger(typeof(Foo))`, for `Bar` it will be `new Logger(typeof(Bar))`, etc.

I would like the proper logger to be injected automatically by Unity; in other words, when I call `container.Resolve<Foo>()`, I want a `new Logger(typeof(Foo))` to be injected into the `Foo` instance.

**How can I set this up in Unity? Is there a way to pass the type being resolved to the dependency?**

(In my real code, I actually have a `ILoggerFactory` with a `Create` method, which also takes a type as a parameter. So I could just pass the factory to my classes, and they would call `Create` themselves to get the appropriate logger, but it's not as elegant as what I'd like to achieve)

---

Some code to make things clearer:

```
interface ILogger
{
    ...
}

class Logger : ILogger
{
    private readonly Type _type;
    public Logger(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }
    ...
}

class Foo
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public Foo(ILogger logger) // here I want a Logger with its type set to Foo
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

---

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790832/ninject-pass-constructor-argument-typeof-class-that-implements-the-interface) shows exactly what I'm trying to do, and the accepted answer is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for... but it's for NInject, not Unity.

Comment: Will `logger = new Logger(GetType());` work for you? GetType() always returns the most derived classes type. I used to pass typeof(class) everywhere but the GetType() method does exactly what I need.

Comment: @Quantic, no it won't. My classes don't know the implementation of `ILogger` (which is the whole point of dependency injection), so they can't create an instance of `Logger`. I think you misunderstood my question, but thanks for trying ;)

Comment: I figured I made a mistake after I saw your reputation and badges heh. I'll go back to my corner ;)

Comment: @antiduh, 3.5.1404. Is there something new in 4.0 that could help?

Comment: @antiduh, I don't think that answer applies to my problem

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790832/ninject-pass-constructor-argument-typeof-class-that-implements-the-interface) is a similar question that is directed for NInject. NInject allows you to access some resolution context that contains the needed information. I don't think that unity supports this without any custom code. Unity can be extended, maybe you can have such support with a custom extension.

Comment: Thanks @YacoubMassad, yes, I'm trying to do something like that. I already tried to write a Unity extension to do something similar, but it went into infinite recursion, not sure why...

Comment: You probably went into infinite recursion because you were trying to resolve a Type. When Unity sees a Type it tries to resolve the object registered with the container of that type and not directly inject a Type object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a container extension that will set the Type parameter of the Logger constructor to the Type that the ILogger is being injected into.

The transient IBuilderContext.Policies is used to store the type that the ILogger is being injected into.

Maybe it's more complicated than it needs to be but this seems to work

```
public class LoggerExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    public static NamedTypeBuildKey LoggerBuildKey = new NamedTypeBuildKey<Logger>();

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Strategies.Add(new LoggerTrackingPolicy(), UnityBuildStage.TypeMapping);
        Context.Strategies.Add(new LoggerBuildUpStrategy(), UnityBuildStage.PreCreation);
    }
}

public class LoggerTrackingPolicy : BuilderStrategy
{
    public LoggerTrackingPolicy()
    {
    }

    public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        if (context.BuildKey.Type != typeof(Logger))
        {
            var loggerPolicy = context.Policies.Get<ILoggerPolicy>(LoggerExtension.LoggerBuildKey);
            if (loggerPolicy == null)
            {
                loggerPolicy = new LoggerPolicy();
                context.Policies.Set<ILoggerPolicy>(loggerPolicy, LoggerExtension.LoggerBuildKey);
            }

            loggerPolicy.Push(context.BuildKey.Type);
        }
    }
}

public class LoggerBuildUpStrategy : BuilderStrategy
{
    public LoggerBuildUpStrategy()
    {
    }

    public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        if (context.BuildKey.Type == typeof(Logger))
        {
            var policy = context.Policies.Get<ILoggerPolicy>(LoggerExtension.LoggerBuildKey);
            Type type = policy.Peek();
            if (type != null)
            {
                context.AddResolverOverrides(new ParameterOverride("type", new InjectionParameter(typeof(Type), type)));
            }
        }
    }

    public override void PostBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        if (context.BuildKey.Type != typeof(Logger))
        {
            var policy = context.Policies.Get<ILoggerPolicy>(LoggerExtension.LoggerBuildKey);
            policy.Pop();
        }
    }
}

public interface ILoggerPolicy : IBuilderPolicy
{
    void Push(Type type);
    Type Pop();
    Type Peek();
}

public class LoggerPolicy : ILoggerPolicy
{
    private Stack<Type> types = new Stack<Type>();

    public void Push(Type type)
    {
        types.Push(type);
    }

    public Type Peek()
    {
        if (types.Count > 0)
        {
            return types.Peek();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Type Pop()
    {
        if (types.Count > 0)
        {
            return types.Pop();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

How it works is: when a type that is not a Logger is trying to be resolved then, during the TypeMapping stage (before any creation), the type is pushed on a stack.  Later, before creation, if the type is a Logger then the type it is being injected into is peeked from the stack and that type used as a resolver override.  After creation, if the type is not a Logger, it is popped from the stack.

And some code to make sure it's working (I added a Type property to the logger just to verify it's set properly):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>();
        container.AddNewExtension<LoggerExtension>();

        var a = container.Resolve<A>();
        var b = container.Resolve<B>();
        var c = container.Resolve<C>();
        var d = container.Resolve<D>();
        var x = container.Resolve<X>();
    }
}

public interface ILogger
{
    Type Type { get; }
}

public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private readonly Type _type;
    public Logger(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }

    public Type Type { get { return _type; } }
}

public class A
{
    public A(ILogger logger)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(logger.Type == typeof(A));
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B(ILogger logger)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(logger.Type == typeof(B));
    }
}

public class C
{
    public C(A a, D d, B b, ILogger logger)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(logger.Type == typeof(C));
    }
}

public class D
{
    public D()
    {
    }
}

public class X
{
    public X(Y y)
    {
    }
}

public class Y
{
    public Y(ILogger logger)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(logger.Type == typeof(Y));
    }
}
```

Comment: Added bug fixes and another test case.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Just tried it, and it works fine. I still have to look into the code to understand how it works, but it seems to be doing exactly what I want.

Comment: I added a bit of a description of what the code is doing.  Also, I'm using the resolved concrete Logger type and not the ILogger interface.  It should be possible to use the ILogger interface instead (use the `context.OriginalBuildKey`) or add the desired concrete type to override as a parameter to the `LoggerExtension`.

Answer (score 0):

As @spotco suggested, I would also recommend generics.  The unity registration would be done using "open generics" as shown here.  This single registration gives you the ability to resolve any type in the generics parameter of Logger.

```
unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
```

Using that registration, you can resolve the instance using constructor injection like this.

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger) { ... }
}
```

[More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936(v=pandp.20).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm trying to do. I don't want to make my interface generic.